# Google analytics Admin installing error in flask

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, google-analytics-4

when installing python pacakage.

##### Environment details

- OS type and version: catalina 10.15.7
- Python version: 3.8.10
- pip version: 21.1.2
- `google-analytics-admin` version: `0.7.2`

##### Steps to reproduce

1. write pipfile `google-analytics-admin
2. execute cmd `install pipenv install google-analytics-admin`
3. occuring error

##### error log

```py
pipenv install
Courtesy Notice: Pipenv found itself running within a virtual environment, so it will automatically use that environment, instead of creating its own for any project. You can set PIPENV_IGNORE_VIRTUALENVS=1 to force pipenv to ignore that environment and create its own instead. You can set PIPENV_VERBOSITY=-1 to suppress this warning.
Pipfile.lock (1a5204) out of date, updating to (e17f24)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
✔ Success! 
Locking [packages] dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2021.5.29/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2021.5.29/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 702, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2021.5.29/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 684, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2021.5.29/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1397, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2021.5.29/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1110, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2021.5.29/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 835, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches graphql-core<3,>=2.1,~=3.1.2 (from -r /var/folders/nd/lsjr321s7sxbss72ggwkq5sr0000gn/T/pipenvvqls7c6mrequirements/pipenv-45xeq_21-constraints.txt (line 14))
Tried: 0.4.9, 0.4.11, 0.4.12, 0.4.12.1, 0.4.13, 0.4.14, 0.4.15, 0.4.16, 0.4.17, 0.4.18, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1, 2.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 2.3.1, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.2, 3.0.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.5, 3.1.0, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.1.4, 3.1.5, 3.1.5, 3.1.6, 3.1.6
Skipped pre-versions: 0.1a0, 0.1a1, 0.1a2, 0.1a3, 0.1a4, 0.4.7b0, 0.4.7b1, 0.4.7b2, 0.5b1, 0.5b2, 0.5b3, 1.0.dev20160814231515, 1.0.dev20160822075425, 1.0.dev20160823054952, 1.0.dev20160909030348, 1.0.dev20160909040033, 1.0.dev20160920065529, 1.2.dev20170724044604, 2.0.dev20170801041408, 2.0.dev20170801041408, 2.0.dev20170801051721, 2.0.dev20170801051721, 2.0.dev20171009101843, 2.0.dev20171009101843, 2.1rc0, 2.1rc0, 2.1rc1, 2.1rc1, 2.1rc2, 2.1rc2, 2.1rc3, 2.1rc3, 3.0.0a0, 3.0.0a0, 3.0.0a1, 3.0.0a1, 3.0.0a2, 3.0.0a2, 3.0.0b0, 3.0.0b0, 3.0.0b1, 3.0.0b1, 3.1.0b0, 3.1.0b0, 3.1.0b1, 3.1.0b1, 3.1.0b2, 3.1.0b2, 3.2.0rc1, 3.2.0rc1, 3.2.0rc2, 3.2.0rc2
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  graphql-core (from -r /var/folders/nd/lsjr321s7sxbss72ggwkq5sr0000gn/T/pipenvvqls7c6mrequirements/pipenv-45xeq_21-constraints.txt (line 14))
  graphql-core<3,>=2.1 (from flask-graphql==2.0.1->-r /var/folders/nd/lsjr321s7sxbss72ggwkq5sr0000gn/T/pipenvvqls7c6mrequirements/pipenv-45xeq_21-constraints.txt (line 13))
  graphql-core~=3.1.2 (from graphene==3.0->-r /var/folders/nd/lsjr321s7sxbss72ggwkq5sr0000gn/T/pipenvvqls7c6mrequirements/pipenv-45xeq_21-constraints.txt (line 21))
```

how to avoid this error ?

Comment: Any chance that you have this in a public repo we can try and build?

Comment: Have you tried `pipenv lock --clear` as suggested in the error log you posted?

Comment: Can you verify you are using this library? [python-analytics-admin](https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-admin)  and not this one [Google api python client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)

Comment: Sorry, I personally solved it. Thank you for your attention.
It was a library conflict issue.